# Loading redirection of page information from db ( Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to redirect incoming users to different codeigniter controllers, I get the controller name and the function of the controller from the database, but for some reason the redirection does not work.

```
$result = $this->mother_page->check_to_path_for_user($country, $from_path, $role);
    /* Now we will use the information from the result to direct the user where they are necessary */
    $this->load->module($result['to_controller']);
    return $this->$result['to_controller']->$result['to_path'];
```

THe above function gets the controller `name` and controller `method name` so the I could redirect the user there, but I am getting this error.

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI::$borrowerssn

Filename: MX/Controller.php

Line Number: 59
```

I checked the `$result` it shows `borrowerssn` and `myprofile` the first one the method name and the second one is the controller, so I am not sure why its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `()` after the `$result['to_path'];`

So it should look like

```
return $this->$result['to_controller']->$result['to_path']();
```